Using a microcontroller to make a bluetooth MP3 player
I need to make a Bluetooth MP3 player for a particular use. I have worked with microcontrollers such as Arduino, RPi, Pic16F and Pic18F, but need a suggestion on how to build for this scenario:
I need to be able to download MP3 or similar audio file in runtime and save it into flash or SD card and need to play it (I can try using an external DAC and amplifier along with it if needed). Also, need to have some functionality to be able to pause, play and move to next audio file.
I am not able to use an ESP32 to download and play in runtime, is there a solution? Or is there any microcontroller that is more suited for this scenario?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can choose a convenient board from here: https://www.sparkfun.com/search/results?term=bluetooth


I need to make a Bluetooth MP3 player for a particular use.

So, you'll want a bluetooth SoC: a microcontroller with integrated Bluetooth functionality.

I need to be able to download MP3 or similar audio file in runtime and save it into flash or SD card and need to play it

There's bluetooth profiles for different use cases. Yours sounds like a file transfer problem – so, something like the OBEX profile. That means you get to modify one of the firmware examples from the Bluetooth SoC manufacturer for that purpose.
You'll need to write something that implements a file system (to store the files you receive, and to be able to read the data as files), which works with a driver for your storage medium (possibly some eMMC/SD card?).
Then, you need to port an MP3 decoder to that same platform.
You will need to attach an audio DAC (typically, one with integrated headphone amplifier) to your microcontroller in order to be able to convert the decoded digital audio into analog audio for your headphones.
Finally, you need to implement all the UI: buttons, display, Bluetooth pairing, receiving files… and connect it all together. At that point, you'll want some kind of RTOS (probably the one that your SoC vendor supports the most) that manages the different tasks for you (namely: decoding, handling incoming bluetooth activity, handling buttons, shuffling data from the storage to the decoder memory, shuffling memory from the decoder output to the audio DAC, updating the display, supervising battery state…)
So, this sounds like a rather large project! I'm not sure I would take on that project as a single engineer if there was any time pressure to get it done.

I am not able to use an ESP32 to download and play in runtime, is there a solution

the ESP32 family is a large family of pretty different chips; some do bluetooth, some do other stuff. And there's infinitely many things that can go wrong – you need to be precise about where you're stuck!

To note there are MP3 player chips like the VS1053B which can play MP3 audio piped to them. That takes care of having to do the MP3 codecs in a microcontroller and the audio output. You might be able to pair this with an Arduino or similar Bluetooth project to reuse existing software components.

@user1908704 definitely. But note that the hard part is still controlling bluetooth and having the file system driver for the storage device. Then using a separate hardware decoder for something as low-effort as MP3 might not be simpler, because you need to multiplex access to the storage medium.
